# How to calculate $ I_2+A+A^2+ ... + A^{2019} $?

Tags: matrices

Let $ A \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ A+A^{-1}=I_2 $.

Calculate $ I_2+A+A^2+ ... + A^{2019} $

I tried this:

$$ A+A^{-1}=I_2 $$
$$ (A+A^{-1})^2=I_2 $$
$$ A^2+2I_2+A^{-2}=I_2 $$
$$ A^2+I_2+A^{-2}=O_2 $$
$$ A^3-A^{-3}=O_2 $$

,but I don't know what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^{2019} + \ldots+x+1$ and $g = x^2-x+1$. Use the fact that $g(A)=  0$ and that there exists a polynomial $r(x)$ and reals $a,b$ such that $f(x) =r(x) g(x) + ax+b$.

Comment: Hint : $A^3+I = (A+I)(A^2 - A + I) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\sum_{k=0}^K A^{k+1}=A\sum_{k=0}^K A^k=(I-A^{-1})\sum_{k=0}^K A^k=\sum_{k=0}^K A^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^K A^{k-1}=A^{K-1}-A^{-1}.$$
Can you continue from here ?

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $$ X:=I+A+A^2+ ... + A^{2019} $$ then $$X(I-A) = I-A^{2020}$$

Since $A^2-A+I=0$ we have $A^3=-I$. So $$X\cdot A^2= I+A\implies X = A^{-2}+A^{-1}=2A^{-1}-I$$

Comment: Doesn't $A^2-A+I$ imply $A^3=-I$? (Showing the derivation would lock that down.) In either case, $A^{-2}$ can be further simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Remark
$$
(I_2+A+\cdots+A^{2019})(A-I_2) = A^{2020}-I_2
$$
And now thanks to the identity $A+A^{-1}=I_2$, one can deduce that
$$
I_2+A+\cdots+A^{2019}= A-A^{2021}
$$